# cannot find device "eth0"

Tags: networking, arch-linux

**Hey Arch linux users out there!**

I am new to arch linux( coming from ubuntu), and have just installed arch linux on my machine.

After rebooting I wanted to install some packages using `pacman -S`, but I saw that my machine wasn't able to fetch the files from the servers, I interrupted the installation ustn `<Ctrl-C>`. So I tried to update my repositorys using `pacman -Sy`, this didn't work because pacman wasn't able to fetch the packages.

So I tried to `ping` a few IPs, wich didn't work because

`network is unreachable`

After that I  tried to set my eth0 up using

`ip link set eth0 up`

it returned me this error:

`cannot find device "eth0"`

the command `ip link` showed that `lo` (of course) and `emp1s0`(what the heck is that?) are up. I tried to set `emp1s0` down using

`ip link set emp1s0 down`

wich returned

`cannot find device "emp1s0"`

I also tried to load the kernel module `tg3` manually and to start `dhcpd` manually, both didn't work.

I actually do't know how to go on.

Comment: Read the [Arch Wiki entry on networking](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Networking)...

Comment: @MattBianco It's `emp1s0`

Comment: @jasonwryan I rade that

Comment: You don't have a "Fritz Box" router and windows on the same computer, do you? It would be nice if you could provide some output from the command `ip a`.

Comment: don't know what I've done, but now It's working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you enabled and started [`systemd-networkd.service`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-networkd)?

First create a file `/etc/systemd/network/mynet.network` containing (if you use DHCP):

```
[Match]
Name=device_name

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

Then issue these commands:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service
systemctl start systemd-networkd.service
```

If that doesn't work (try rebooting aterwards in case you've been trying many things since last boot), boot from the install cd again and see what modules are loaded and try to find differences between the running environment when booting from harddisk and from cd.

The ArchLinux installation guide is a bit tricky to follow for first-time users. Some crucial information are not on the "first" page, such as network configuration and boot loader. In that respect, I find the gentoo handbook a lot more readable.

Comment: when running `systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service` it returns me the error code `no such file or directory`

Comment: Have you removed the installation CD and booted from the hard drive? Did you install GRUB as a boot loader?

Comment: yes and yes and I enabled Grub promt

Comment: Have you logged in normally, then, or are you at a rescue/single user prompt? (can you switch tty with Alt-F1, Alt-F2 and so on?)

Comment: I'm logged in as root on multi user mode (but `runlevel` returns `unknown`) but now it's working.

Answer (score 3):

`emp1s0` is the new [Consistent Network Device Naming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Network_Device_Naming) name for `eth0`.

Use it where you would have used `eth0` in the past and it will be fine.

It can be disabled if you insist on returning to `eth0` by creating an empty:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules
```

Comment: ok, but why haven't I got internet acces?

Comment: Don't know :-) Try posting the output of `ip link`, `ip addr`, `ip route` in your answer and people may be able to help.

Comment: `ip link` see in my question;`ip route`:no output;`ip addr` only  more output about `lo`

Comment: "ok, but why haven't I got internet acces?" - because your config-scripts still assume that your NIC is called "eth0"?

Comment: @countermode  Hey! that was it!